# Proxy undefined type

Tags: c++, proxy

I have been working on this issue for three days. I've been Googling a lot and couldn't come up with an solution. Any help would be appreciated.

I got the following errors and don't know how I should fix:

> Severity Code File Project Description Line Error C2027
> C:\Users\PassionateProgrammer\Documents\Test\ProxyTest.cpp Proxy use
> of undefined type 'VaddV' 14
>
> Severity Code File Project Description Line Error (active) E0409
> C:\Users\PassionateProgrammer\Documents\Test\ProxyTest.cpp Proxy
> function "operator+" returns incomplete type "VaddV" 14
>
> Severity Code File Project Description Line Error C2679
> C:\Users\PassionateProgrammer\Documents\Test\ProxyTest.cpp Proxy
> binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type
> 'VaddV' (or there is no acceptable conversion) 14

*class VaddV is a proxy and **must not** implement inside the class Vect2D.*

**Proxy.cpp**

```
#include "Proxy.h"


class VaddV
{
public:
    const Vect2D& v1;
    const Vect2D& v2;
    VaddV(const VaddV& tmp) = default;
    VaddV& operator= (const VaddV&) = default;
    inline VaddV(const Vect2D& t1, const Vect2D& t2);
    operator Vect2D() {
        return Vect2D(v1.x + v2.x, v1.y + v2.y);

    }

    ~VaddV() = default;



};

inline VaddV operator+(const Vect2D& a1, const Vect2D& a2)
{
    return VaddV(a1, a2);
}
inline VaddV::VaddV(const Vect2D& t1, const Vect2D& t2):
    v1(t1), v2(t2)
{

}
```

**Proxy.h**

```
#ifndef PROXY_H
#define PROXY_H
class Vect2D
{
public:
    Vect2D(const Vect2D& tmp) = default;
    Vect2D& operator =(const Vect2D& tmp) = default;
    Vect2D() = default;
    ~Vect2D() = default;

    Vect2D(const float inX, const float inY);

    void setX(const float inX);
    void setY(const float inY);
    void set(const float inX, const float inY);

    float getX() const;
    float getY() const;


// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Rules: 
//  
//    No implementation in Header
//
// 
//    
//        Proxy is the only thing that can have the keyword "inline"
//            inline only for substitution resolving.. that's it
//                No constructors or other operators... only proxy for substitution purpose
//   
//        No proxy implementation in header
//            conversion operator needs to be implemented in CPP file
//            proxy constructor are allowed in header (only exception)
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

public:
    float x;
    float y;

};

class VaddV;
inline  VaddV operator+(const Vect2D& a1, const Vect2D& a2);

#endif
```

**ProxyTest.cpp**

```
#include "Proxy.h"
int main()
{

    volatile float v1 = 2.0f;
    volatile float v2 = 3.0f;
    Vect2D A;
    A.set(0.0f, 0.0f);
    Vect2D B;
    B.setX(v1);
    B.setY(v2);
    Vect2D sum;
    sum.set(0.0f, 0.0f);
    sum = A + B;

}

// ---  End of File ---------------
```

Comment: Are you sure that `No implementation in Header` means you must put the entire _class_ definition in the .cpp file? Typically, you would put the class definition in the header file while forward-declaring all its member functions, then define the member functions in the source file. Right now, there's no way you can write `sum = A + B;` in `main` without making the `VaddV` class definition available in `Proxy.h`.

Comment: Thank you so much one thousand times. I think you are right. I thought we should put the entire class in the .cpp file. I've got stuck for three days on it. I just did what you said and it worked. Thank you Thank you.